# RestTemplate URI template syntax

Tags: java, spring, templates, uri

In my project, I'm using RestTempate in a client app to access existing service. Service itself returns a list of valid URI templates, and one that I'm trying to use looks like

```
http://corpdomain.com/service{?idparam}
```

At runtime, it should expand to something like

```
http://corpdomain.com/service?idparam=12345
```

Problem is, RestTemplate's getForObject() does not know what to do with "{?idparam}" notation. If I feed it the URI
`http://corpdomain.com/service?idparam={idparam}`, everything works fine. But this is not the URI template that server returns to me.

Do you know how to make RestTemplate.getForObject() working with {?idparam} type notation in template?

Do you know if there is ANY documentation out there regarding the syntax of URI templates?

I'm currently going through spring's java sources and eventually should be able to figure out the solution. However, what really bugs me is the lack of documentation or third party information.

Thanks everybody in advance!

Comment: All right, looks like I figured out what is going on. Shorthand notation `http://corpdomain.com/service{?idparam}` is not coming from any of the Spring libraries, it is constructed using Affordance library (https://github.com/dschulten/hydra-java). But I still don't understand why neither Spring nor Affordance tried to document URI template formats that they are using.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like the service is returning RFC 6570 URI templates, which include notations like `{?foo}` and `{+foo}` that are [are not supported by Spring](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-10505).

There is a library [Handy URI Templates](https://github.com/damnhandy/Handy-URI-Templates) that implements the RFC 6570 spec.

Answer (score 2):

You can either pass uri variables as part of getForObject method

```
getForObject(String url, Class<T> responseType, Map<String,?> uriVariables)
```

Docs: http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html

or else you can make use of build and expand method of UriComponentsBuilder  like below :

```
        String url="http://localhost:8080/test?idparam={idparam}";
        RestTemplate restTemplate=new RestTemplate();
        Map<String,String> uriVariables=new HashMap<String,String>();
        uriVariables.put("idparam", "1234");
        UriComponents builder=UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(url).buildAndExpand(uriVariables);
        System.out.println(" url built "+builder.toUri());
```

Output:

```
 url built http://localhost:8080/test?idparam=1234
```

In case, query params are dynamic as you are not sure what url is going to get passed, you can do like below :

```
    UriComponentsBuilder builder=UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(url);
    Map<String,String> uriVariables =builder.build().getQueryParams().toSingleValueMap();
    //set or get required query params
    restTemplate.getForObject(url, String.class, uriVariables);
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with that syntax.  However I would define a `BASE_SERVICE_URL` and use that with a `UriComponentsBuilder` to make your URL.  It would look something like this

```
  private static final String BASE_SERVICE_URL = "http://corpdomain.com/service"

    public void doTheThing(String idParam) {
    ...
    UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(url)
            .queryParam("idparam", idparam)
    ...
    HttpEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(
        builder.build().encode().toUri(), 
        HttpMethod.GET, 
        entity, 
        String.class);
    }
```

Comment: That approach would work, however, my problem is that I'm trying not to build the URI myself. I'm trying to rely on the template that the service is returning to me, so my client doesn't need to have knowledge to do `.queryParam("idparam", idparam)`

Comment: If the server is returning a non standard syntax, you will have to do some parsing on your end to transform {?somequerystringvar} into something that  spring will understand.  I could be wrong, but I have not seen that syntax before, it could be standard for all I know.  Maybe you could implement a method that takes all occurances of {?queryparam} in a URI to the ?queryparam=queryparamvalue syntax

Comment: @ferahgo the server is returning an [rfc6570 level 4](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6570#section-3.2.8) standard uri template. Spring only understands level 1.